# Is there some "standard" "elementary functions" support for fixed point data types in Ada?

Tags: ada

Is there some "standard" [elementary functions](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-5-1.html) support for fixed point data types in Ada?

I would like to implement some stuff requiring `exp` on MCUs without fixed-point unit, partially even very slow multiplication, but would like to spare the time to implement, and especially test, it myself.

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: Why not a [_power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) or [_lookup table_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table)?

Comment: @trashgod Probably I will go with something like a power series (have more CPU time to spend than memory for LUTs) or a mixed approach.
I just wanted to confirm that I have to do it really manually.
I know this issue already from C, but was surprised to have it again with a language which has fixed point built in since long or perhaps ever.